# Cplex not meeting lower bound in quadratic programming (using Python API)

Tags: python, cplex, quadratic-programming

I am trying to solve a quadratic programming problem with k unknowns. The problem is separable, i.e. all non-diagonals are zero in the Q matrix which defines the problem. There are some linear constraints as well.

I find that Cplex gives solutions which do not meet the zero lower bound. I cannot figure out what is wrong with the way I enter the problem into Cplex which generates such solutions. Note that min v is negative, whereas I'd like all values in v to be between 0 and 1.

My code below.

```
from __future__ import division
import cplex
from cplex.exceptions import CplexError

k = 29

prob = cplex.Cplex()
prob.objective.set_sense(prob.objective.sense.minimize)
separable = [1.0] * k
prob.objective.set_quadratic(separable)
my_ub = [1.0] * k
my_lb = [0.0] * k
prob.variables.add(ub=my_ub, lb=my_lb)

my_rhs = [10.1, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 4.1, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 4.1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
my_sense = 'EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE'
prob.linear_constraints.add(rhs=my_rhs, senses=my_sense)
constraints_rowColVal = [(0, 9, 3.1), (0, 11, 3.1), (0, 13, 3.1), (0, 15, 3.1), (0, 17, 4.1), (0, 20, 3.1), (0, 22, 3.1), (0, 24, 3.1), (0, 26, 4.1), (1, 0, 10.1), (1, 14, 3.1), (1, 25, 3.1), (1, 27, 4.1), (2, 1, 10.1), (2, 10, 3.1), (2, 21, 3.1), (2, 28, 4.1), (3, 2, 10.1), (3, 12, 3.1), (4, 3, 10.1), (5, 4, 10.1), (5, 16, 3.1), (6, 5, 10.1), (6, 18, 4.1), (7, 6, 10.1), (7, 19, 4.1), (8, 7, 10.1), (8, 23, 3.1), (9, 8, 10.1), (10, 0, 1), (10, 1, 1), (10, 2, 1), (10, 3, 1), (10, 4, 1), (10, 5, 1), (10, 6, 1), (10, 7, 1), (10, 8, 1), (11, 9, 1), (11, 10, 1), (12, 11, 1), (12, 12, 1), (13, 13, 1), (13, 14, 1), (14, 15, 1), (14, 16, 1), (15, 17, 1), (15, 18, 1), (15, 19, 1), (16, 20, 1), (16, 21, 1), (17, 22, 1), (17, 23, 1), (18, 24, 1), (18, 25, 1), (19, 26, 1), (19, 27, 1), (19, 28, 1)]
prob.linear_constraints.set_coefficients(constraints_rowColVal)

prob.solve()
v = prob.solution.get_values()
print min(v)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your model is infeasible. Try adding the following line of code, just after calling the `solve` method:

```
print("Solution status: {0} ({1})".format(
    prob.solution.get_status_string(),
    prob.solution.get_status()
))
```

You should see the following:

```
Solution status: infeasible (3)
```

You should always check the solution status after solving. Otherwise, as you have seen, the solution results will not make any sense.

You can use the [conflict refiner](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/UsrMan/topics/infeas_unbd/conflict_refiner/01_ref_confl_title_synopsis.html) in the [Python API](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refpythoncplex/html/cplex._internal._subinterfaces.ConflictInterface-class.html#refine) or the interactive to understand where the problems might be.